# Running subsetting function over multiple excel sheets and multiple files

Tags: r, excel, loops, for-loop

I have inherited a bunch of excel files, each containing multiple sheets.
Each sheet looks something like this:

```
str(mydata)
'data.frame':   29 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ Gyffin    : Factor w/ 11 levels "% of total activity added",..: 9 NA 11 4        7 5 6 8 NA NA ...
 $ X2.5.hours: Factor w/ 19 levels "-0.413614051315461",..: 13 8 NA 14 12 11 10 9 NA NA ...
 $ X24.hours : num  5887 NA NA 6310 6291 ...
 $ X48.hours : num  5837 NA NA 6370 6201 ...
 $ X72.hours : Factor w/ 19 levels "-0.112994944133188",..: 10 NA 19 13 12 11 9 8 NA NA ...
 $ NA.       : Factor w/ 15 levels "0","0.314915755033141",..: NA NA 15 10 11 12 13 14 NA NA ...
 $ NA..1     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NA..2     : Factor w/ 19 levels "0","100","1271.6",..: 15 6 NA 7 12 5 3 4 NA NA ...
 $ NA..3     : num  NA NA NA 2947 3241 ...
 $ NA..4     : num  NA NA NA 2817 3605 ...
 $ NA..5     : Factor w/ 18 levels "0","100","1520.4",..: NA NA 18 8 10 5 4 3 NA NA ...
 $ NA..6     : Factor w/ 16 levels "0","1.88229983116934",..: NA NA 16 13 11 8 7 6 NA NA ...
 $ NA..7     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NA..8     : Factor w/ 19 levels "0","10.3482969177356",..: 13 5 NA 7 6 11 15 14 NA NA ...
 $ NA..9     : num  NA NA NA 3963 2736 ...
 $ NA..10    : num  NA NA NA 3504 2762 ...
 $ NA..11    : Factor w/ 18 levels "0","100","2805.56666666667",..: NA NA 18 4 3 8 10 7 NA NA ...
 $ NA..12    : Factor w/ 12 levels "0","0.290827113462025",..: NA NA 12 7 10 8 6 11 NA NA ...
 $ NA..13    : Factor w/ 19 levels "0","100","14C Glucose-6-phosphate",..: 12 3 NA 7 11 9 10 8 NA NA ...
 $ NA..14    : num  NA NA NA 4300 5045 ...
 $ NA..15    : num  NA NA NA 4367 5090 ...
 $ NA..16    : Factor w/ 18 levels "0","1.23360797663463",..: NA NA 18 8 10 6 9 7 NA NA ...
 $ NA..17    : Factor w/ 15 levels "0","0.132468292842382",..: NA NA 15 9 8 7 14 6 NA NA ...
```

I want to run the following subsetting code:

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("All sites July_Aug 2015.xlsx", sheetName = "Gyffin")
uptake <- mydata[23:28,]
uptake_1 <- uptake[c(1,5,6,11,12,17,18,22,23)]
library(plyr)
uptake_2 <- rename(uptake_1,c("Gyffin" = "Time", "X72.hours" = "Mean_1", "NA." = "SEM_1", "NA..5" = "Mean_2", "NA..6" = "SEM_2", "NA..11" = "Mean_3", "NA..12" = "SEM_3", "NA..16" = "Mean_4", "NA..17" = "SEM_4"))
```

uptake_2

And then export to csv:

```
write.csv(uptake_2, "Gyffin_Summer_Uptake.csv")
```

So I'm after help with writing a loop so I can run the above code over every sheet within every file with the directory. I've managed to create for loops to produce graphs from multiple .csv files but I'm totally stumped with this.

Comment: If you've done for loops before, you're not totally stumped. Looping sheets and files in a directory are very common. There are numerous questions and answers here on SO and google.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function in a loop. Create a vector with all of your file names and one with output file names:

```
library(plyr)
excel_files <- all-of-your-file-names-here..
output_file_names <- output-file-names-here..

for(i in all_files) {
  mydata <- read.xlsx(excel_files[i], sheetName = "Gyffin")
  uptake <- mydata[23:28,]
  uptake_1 <- uptake[c(1,5,6,11,12,17,18,22,23)]
  uptake_2 <- rename(new-names-here..
  write.csv(uptake_2, output_file_names[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem with this is that it will only run for `sheetName = "Gyffin"`. I need the function to loop over every sheet within each excel file

Comment: do you have a set of replacement column names for each sheet?

Comment: same column names for each sheet as written above

Comment: You will have to most likely use `openxlsx` in conjunction with the loop. The three functions you need are `loadWorkbook` to get the excel file, `writeData` to edit each sheet, and `saveWorkbook` to save the file. I can't do the whole thing right now but research those three functions. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf

Comment: It may help to break your task into smaller problems, because as you asked it, someone will have to provide code for your entire project to answer it.